# My running java code is showing repeated initialized/terminated statements in console

Tags: java, multithreading, legacy, jconsole

I'm running a multi-threaded java application that's running on JDK 1.6 because it is running on a legacy environment.

When I start it, it immediately is showing nonstop output in the console that consists of:

> (java)Initialized 6084:5848 (java)Terminated 6084 :5835
>   (java)Initialized 6084:5849 (java)Terminated 6084:5837
>   (java)Initialized 6 084:5850 (java)Terminated 6084:5838
>   (java)Initialized 6084:5851 (java)Terminated  6084:5840
>   (java)Initialized 6084:5852 (java)Terminated 6084:5846 (java)Initiali
>   zed 6084:5853

Does anyone one know what this console output means and what it says about the current condition of the code?

I checked my logs and everything looks good.  I checked memory and cpu and there is no problem that I can see.  The java process for example is running as expected.

The only concern is the repeated output message.  I checked the web but couldn't find any reference to this situation.  I've run the code many times and have never seen this happen.

Comment: Please provide the relevant source code which is generating the log above.

Comment: I am not sure which code is causing it.  Has anyone seen anything like this before?